# UI of Fragment with tabs is not being updated

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two tabs which contain two different fragments. `Tab1` for `fragment1` and `tab2` for `fragment2`. From `fragment1`, I want to pass a string value in `fragment2`'s TextView by clicking on a Button.
However, the UI of `fragment2` is not being updated. Sample code has given below.

**In MainActivity :**

```
private Fragment1 fragment1;
private Fragment2 fragment2;
private TabLayout tabLayout;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    fragment2 = new Fragment2();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment1).commit();

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment1).commit();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment2).commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    }

}

public void showFragment2(final String data) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment2).commit();
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data)) {
        if (fragment2 != null) {
            fragment2.setData(data);
        }
    }
}
```

**In Fragment1 :**

```
 private Button button;

protected void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showFragment2("Updated Data");
        }
    });
}
```

**In Fragment2 :**

```
private TextView tv;
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
}

public void setData(String data){
    tv.setText(data);
}
```

**Important Update:** 
If I update the UI in **Handler**. Then it works. But, seems it's not the proper way.

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(data)){
                if(fragment2 != null){
                    fragment2.setData(data);
                }
            }
        }
    },500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **.executePendingTransactions()** which would work synchronously along with **.commit()** which works Asynchronously.

> After a FragmentTransaction is committed with 
>   **FragmentTransaction.commit()**, it is scheduled to be executed
>   asynchronously on the process's main thread. If you want to
>   immediately executing any such pending operations, you can call this
>   function (only from the main thread) to do so. Note that all callbacks
>   and other related behavior will be done from within this call, so be
>   careful about where this is called from.

**DO:**

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment2).commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(data)){
           if(fragment2 != null){
              fragment2.setData(data);
           }
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't find anything called .executePendingTransactions() in place of .commit()

Answer (score 0):

Hey hi i am not sure but try this:

```
public void showFragment2(final String data) {

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data)) {
            if (fragment2 != null) {
//                fragment2.setData(data);
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString( "string_key" , data);
                fragment2.setArguments(arguments);
            }
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment2).commit();
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
    }
```

and In Fragment2 :

```
private TextView tv;
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        String desired_string = arguments.getString("string_key");

        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        setData(desired_string);

        }

public void setData(String data){
        tv.setText(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

set the data in activity method from fragment 1 and while loading fragment get the data from activity and set it in fragment 2

```
 mainActivity(){
string fragment1Data;

public void setFragment1Data(string data){
fragment1Data = data;
}

public string getFragment1Data(){
return fragment1Data 
}
}
```

in Fragment 1

```
private Button button;
protected void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showFragment2("Updated Data");
       ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setFragment1Data("data");
    }
});
}
```

in Fragment 2

```
 private TextView tv;
 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText(((MainActivity)getActivity()).getFragment1Data());

}
```